# Handle optional JSON field in HTTP request body

Tags: json, go

I have a struct like this:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Age   int    `json:"age"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
}
```

Then I have some value (could be default, which means I do not need to update this value) to feed in as HTTP request data.  I noticed the generated JSON body will always contains all three fields (`name`, `age` and `email`), even if I don't need to update all of them. Like this:

```
{
  "name":"Kevin",
  "age":10,
  "email":""
}
```

Is there a way to Marshal so that the JSON body contains not all fields with the same struct?  Example:

```
{
  "name":"kevin"
}
```

Comment: Basically I want something like `undefined` in JavaScript (so that field wont be in part of the body).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You want to use the `omitempty` option

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Name  string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Age   int    `json:"age"`
    Email string `json:"email,omitempty"`
}
```

If you want `Age` to be optional as well you have to use a pointer, since the zero value of an `int` isn't really "empty"

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Name  string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Age   *int   `json:"age,omitempty"`
    Email string `json:"email,omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: Where is the list of all options? Can you provide a reference link?

Comment: You can find the list of all options in the package documentation (currently hosted at https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) which is extracted from the source `src/encoding/json/encode.go` that you can read online on the official Go source repository https://cs.opensource.google/go/go or in it's https://github.com/golang/go/ mirror.